# H2O2 (Hydrogen Peroxide) catalysis in clear plastic bottle?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, catalysis

I am buying some 30% H2O2 which will be in probably black HDPE bottles. If I want to make some 3% - 5% solution, can I store that in clear bottles? How much faster will it catalyse versus having it in a dark bottle?

Will shelf life be significantly shorter? How much effect does sunlight (or other light) have on the H2O2 solution? Any way to measure this?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy test for this would be to react H2O2 with yeast or baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) before and after sun bathing. Or you could simply measure gas production in the sun vs in a box for say 24 hours.

An easy way to measure the O2 released is to use a closed vessel with a ballon, but [the more scientific method](http://ask.metafilter.com/96719/How-to-measure-the-volume-of-gas-produced) uses an inverted, graduated column.

[image]

You can [measure light intensity with a photometer](http://www.wikihow.com/Measure-Light-Intensity).

[image]

Comment: The 3% - 5% solution is fine with baker's yeast? It won't kill the micro-organism?

Comment: Yes it will kill yeast and react quickly (like a 3rd grade valcano). You need enough yeast to completely react with all of the H2O2. I would recommend using a syringe to inject H2O2 through a rubber septum into a distillation flask with an excess amount yeast. Kind of like picture #1 above. Or you could use baking soda. Or you don't have to use anything if you just put clean H2O2 in a closed vessel (with a balloon maybe) in the sun, you will see how much O2 is released during the day. However, balloons leak slowly and water will absorb some gas... so measuring quickly is more accurate.

Comment: Ah, ok I understand now.